# Computer Software patent applications rejected in the UK - Can it still be granted in Europe/US?

Tags: patentability, software, computer

I understand Europe/US have relaxed the regulations surrounding computer software patents, whilst the UK remains somewhat rigid. Thus, would it stand that if such an application was rejected in the UK it may still be granted in Europe/US?

Answer (score 1):

One place loves it and another rejects it or demands changes in opposite directions - yes!  Every jurisdiction has their own laws and rules, obviously. Defining what a software patent is and how the line is drawn between patent-eligible subject matter and not patent-eligible matter is messy and a moving target in the US and elsewhere.

I am involved with a patent on a very prosaic, very tangible thing and it sailed through Australia but may have hit a wall in China.